# How perform a self-join to divide the records in table into groups of transactions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables which look like this.  How to match/Find the unifiednumber from #tblregister to #tblheader like the sample I gave.  every pid number should have the  IN-BD (No clean)and IP-BM (clean). meaning the poolnum IN-BD  will be the first to transact then followed by IP-BM.

There is a possibility the recoverednum  will come back again and create a new pid# with the same unifiednumber and then they will transact a new details. Thank you.

```
Create table #tblRegister
(   esnnum nvarchar(50),
    recoverednum nvarchar(50), 
    receiptdate datetime, 
    pid nvarchar(10), 
    createddatetime datetime,
    unifiednumber nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #tblRegister (esnnum,recoverednum,receiptdate,pid, createddatetime, unifiednumber) values
('T008311518089249843905318439','B89249843905318439','2016-10-08 12:39:00.000','T008311518','2016-10-13 04:27:31.000','T49843905318439M'),
('T008311518089249843905318439','B89249843905318439','2016-11-05 11:11:00.000','T008524845','2016-11-16 08:50:51.000','T49843905318439M')


Create table #tblHeader
(   unifiednumber nvarchar(50),
    pid nvarchar(10), 
    poolnum nvarchar(10),
    startdate datetime,
    enddate datetime,
    linenum nvarchar(20)
)
insert into #tblHeader ( unifiednumber, pid, poolnum, startdate, enddate,linenum ) values
('T49843905318439M','P07037433','IN-BD','2016-10-13 16:19:46.000','2016-10-14 01:23:42.000','tb_tb-BD1'),
('T49843905318439M','P07370491','IP-BM','2016-11-07 11:14:30.000','2016-11-08 05:15:30.000','tb_BM3'),

('T49843905318439M','P07418769','IN-BD','2016-11-09 16:07:07.000','2016-11-13 04:10:30.000','tb_tb-BD1'),
('T49843905318439M','P07590987','IN-BD','2016-11-18 03:22:43.000','2016-11-18 22:41:50.000','tb_tb-BD1')
```

Desired Result: the first line is already complete with matching poolnum "IN-BD" and "IP-BM". the second line is not yet complete. it has transacted the 'No Clean' with transaction poolnum IN-BD .

```
esnnum-------------------------recoverednum--------receiptdate-------------createddatetime-----------unifiednumber-----poolnum-A--pid-A--------linenum-A--------------startdate-----------enddate--------------poolnum-B--linenum-B---pid-B----
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
T008311518089249843905318439---B89249843905318439--2016-10-08 12:39:00.000--2016-10-13 04:27:31.000--T49843905318439M--IN-BD------P07037433---tb_tb-BD1---2016-11-9 16:19:46.000--2016-11-13 01:23:42.000-----'IP-BM'-----tb_BM3-----'P07370491'
T008311518089249843905318439---B89249843905318439--2016-11-05 11:11:00.000--2016-11-16 08:50:51.000--T49843905318439M--IN-BD------P07590987---tb_tb-BD1---2016-11-18 03:22:43.000--2016-11-18 22:41:50.000--------------------------------------
```

Comment: And what is the relation between the first one and the second one?

Comment: The relation would be the unifiednumber.

Comment: @Kaniguan how  come ? the unifiednumber is only one value in the both tables > `T49843905318439M` it is not logic.

Comment: #tblRegister the is the header transaction which the reference is the unifiednumber. When they start transaction is production the #tblHeader is the details which they used also the unifiednumber as reference.

Comment: depends on ur comment, the `unifiednumber` should be `unique` in `#tblRegister` but this is not existing !

Answer (score 0):

Just made the script and Based on the result of this script the second row is correct but the first row the startdate and enddate should be this '2016-11-09 16:07:07.000','2016-11-13 04:10:30.000' not the one captured.

I have to breakdown based on poolnum and get first the poolnum='IN-BD'.

```
;with cte as
(
 select unifiednumber, pid, poolnum, startdate, enddate, linenum,
  row_number() over(partition by unifiednumber order by startdate) row_num

 from #tblHeader 
 where poolnum='IN-BD'
)--, cte2 as

 select 
            rs1.unifiednumber, rs1.pid, rs1.poolnum, rs1.startdate, rs1.enddate, rs1.linenum,
            isnull(rs3.startdate,dateadd(year,-2,rs1.startdate)) previous_audit_date,
         isnull(rs2.startdate,dateadd(year,2,rs1.startdate)) next_audit_date,
                  rs1.row_num,
         rs2.row_num as rownum2,
         rs3.row_num as rownum3
into #data
from     cte rs1
         left join cte rs2 
            on rs1.unifiednumber = rs2.unifiednumber
            and rs1.row_num + 1 = rs2.row_num
         left join cte rs3
            on rs1.unifiednumber = rs3.unifiednumber
            and rs1.row_num - 1 = rs3.row_num


select tcps.esnnum, tcps.recoverednum, tcps.receiptdate, tcps.createddatetime, tcps.unifiednumber,
        pno.poolnum, pno.pid, pno.linenum, pno.startdate, pno.enddate
from #tblRegister tcps
         left join #data pno
                    on tcps.unifiednumber = pno.unifiednumber collate chinese_taiwan_stroke_ci_as
                    and tcps.createddatetime between pno.previous_audit_date and pno.startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below sample data as reference. hope this is clear now. thank you.

```
register data:

itemcode      |ponum        |id2  |item |wrkctr |serialid |em_serial |date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A5912947270138|P008279816   |S7843|A13  |FEntry |12345678F|aaaaaaaaaa|2016-10-07 06:20:54.000
A5912947270138|P008508629   |S8479|A13  |FEntry |12345678F|bbbbbbbbbb|2016-11-14 06:32:58.000
A5936181820133|P008281945   |S7809|A24  |FEntry |56789045D|ffffffffff|2016-10-07 14:48:13.000
A5936181820133|P008510773   |S8482|A24  |FEntry |56789045D|gggggggggg|2016-11-14 09:36:37.000



details data:

|line   |pool|  ponum   |itemid |location   |date                   |serialid
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
L01     |PC  |P06965620 |pc13-t |Entry      |2016-10-08 08:34:53.000|12345678F  
L01     |PC  |P06965620 |pc13-t |Reject     |2016-10-08 08:44:45.000|12345678F  
L01     |PC  |P07628121 |pc24-t |Entry      |2016-11-19 17:03:27.000|56789045D  
L01     |PC  |P07628121 |pc24-T |Reject     |2016-11-19 17:37:18.000|56789045D  
L01     |PC  |P07891150 |pc24-t |Entry      |2016-12-06 17:07:40.000|56789045D  
L01     |PC  |P07891150 |pc24-t |Reject     |2016-12-06 17:17:18.000|56789045D


Desired Result:

|wrkctr |serialid |em_serial |date                   |date2                  |location1|date3                  |location2|itemid
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|FEntry |12345678F|aaaaaaaaaa|2016-10-07 06:20:54.000|2016-10-08 08:34:53.000|Entry    |2016-10-08 08:44:45.000|Reject   |pc13-t
|FEntry |12345678F|bbbbbbbbbb|2016-11-14 06:32:58.000|                       |         |                       |
|FEntry |56789045D|ffffffffff|2016-10-07 14:48:13.000|2016-11-19 17:03:27.000|Entry    |2016-11-19 17:37:18.000|Reject   |pc24-t    
|FEntry |56789045D|gggggggggg|2016-11-14 09:36:37.000|2016-12-06 17:17:18.000|Entry    |2016-12-06 17:17:18.000|Reject   |pc24-t
```